# x-magento-init not working in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, login, requirejs, initialize-script

I have Need to run some script after logged in admin user in magento 2.

But, Its not calling for me.

What i did:

I have created js file this location.

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/seo_field.js`

**seo_field.js**

```
   define([
        "jquery"
    ], function($){

        console.log('user logged  in');
    });
```

Then create my Observer:

`app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/BackendAuthUserLoginSuccess.php`

**BackendAuthUserLoginSuccess.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class BackendAuthUserLoginSuccess implements ObserverInterface
    {

        protected $logger;


        protected $_request;

        protected $authSession;

        public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
            \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession

        )
        {
            $this->logger = $logger;
            $this->_request = $request;
            $this->authSession = $authSession;

        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {

            if ($this->authSession->getUser()->getAclRole() == 4) { ?>

                <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                    {
                        "*": {
                            "Vendor_Module/js/seo_field":{}
                        }
                    }

                </script>
                <?php $this->logger->addDebug($this->authSession->getUser()->getEmail());
            }
        }
    }
```

After Called this Observer, its does not call this `x-magento-init`

Suggest me, What's problem in this code and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this method for adminhtml but I presume it's the same as on the frontend, in which case you're missing `js` from your path. Try changing

```
"Vendor_Module/seo_field"
```

to

```
"Vendor_Module/js/seo_field"
```

Comment: its not works for me

Comment: Damn it, that's my only input as I'm a front-end dev so I can't help with the rest of the code sorry. I still think this is correct though so hopefully it helps once the main issue is resolved. Good luck!